# DJango authentication User search not working properly

Tags: django, authentication

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
1. Retrieve a User record (from the DJango authentication system) is in
    the DB
2. get the Username (from that record)
3. Use the "username" to look for a record in a *different* table.
4. If the record *is not* there (in the *different* table), then create one.
```

I am getting an error on what looks like the query into the User table even though I have the following in the views.py

> from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Also, it is not clear why the **DoesNotExist** error is taking place (when one is looking for the User in the authentication system).  Why am I getting this error?

TIA

**This is the error message**
[image]

**This is how the "app" is structured**

[image]

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from authinduction.models import Mstrauthownerrdx
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def inductowner(request):

    username = request.POST.get('username')
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    myprofile = user.userprofileinfo

    num_results = Mstrauthownerrdx.objects.filter(logonid=username).count()

    if not ( num_results == 0  or num_results == 1 ):
        raise ValueError('Number of items found '+ num_results + ' is not valid')

    if num_results == 0:
        u = Mstrauthownerrdx.objects.create(logonid=username, emailaddr=user.email,
                worktype=1, memo='OWNER', active=1, formpagelastfilled=myprofile.lastpgprocno,
                formcomplete=myprofile.nextpgprocno, reclocktype=1, reclockid=1)

        u.save()

    return render(request, 'authinduction/owner/index.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user you are trying to get doesn't exists. Try to find out what your exact `username` variable says and check it with the database in the admin. You'll see it doesn't exist. For example you could do the following to catch the error:

```
try:
     user = User.objects.get(username=username)
     myprofile = user.userprofileinfo
     num_results = Mstrauthownerrdx.objects.filter(logonid=username).count()
except User.DoesNotExist:
     num_results = 0
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I saw that the reason why I was not getting the value to come back is because this part of the code: " username = request.POST.get('username')" was returning None.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a GET request. While in your code you're trying to get the username from `username` POST parameter. Since the view doesn't have a username your view is trying to fetch the `User` object with no `username` which I am afraid doesn't exist in your database.

For fixing it, you have to either pass the `username` as a GET parameter or send a POST request with `username` as a parameter.